# Compile errors for writing to a file in C++

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong. Based on the compiler's output, every line must include at least an error. But the C2297 error, doesn't seem to make much sense since I found examples of writes with a constant `char` array [cplusplus.com tutorial](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/files/)?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "accelerators/tree.h"
#include "paramset.h"
#include "shapes/trianglemesh.h"

void Tree::PrintTree() const {
    std::ofstream myfile;
    myfile.open("RTSAH.txt");

    for (uint32_t i = 0; i < nextFreeNode; ++i) {
        const KdAccelNode* node = &nodes[i];
        if (node->IsLeaf()) {
            myfile << i;
            myfile << " L ";
            myfile << node->nPrimitives() << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            myfile << i;
            myfile << " I ";
            myfile << "SP= ";
            myfile << node->SplitPos();
            myfile << " SA= ";
            myfile << node->SplitAxis();
            myfile << " BC= ";
            myfile << (i + 1);
            myfile << " AC= ";
            myfile << node->AboveChild() << std::endl;
        }
    }
    myfile.close();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Maybe you should disable 'Unicode' in your project options.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg 'myfile' is a local variable of the 'PrintTree' method.

Comment: Yeah I saw that as soon as I posted the comment. Sorry about that.

Comment: However, which VisualStudio version are you using? And the initial error is the first one, where, for some reason, the compiler doesn't know what `std::ofstream` is, the rest are just depending on that single error.

Comment: Visual Studio 2013 Professional/Ultimate

Comment: @LewisCheng same problem for the multi-byte character set

Comment: This is not compiler output.

Comment: @AlexFarber it's the build output.

Comment: Are you sure you `#include <fstream> `? I get similar errors without it

Comment: So even trying 'std::wofstream' and prefixing each string with L"xxx", you will get the error std::basic_ofstream<wchar_t> not defined too?

Comment: @doctorlove #include <fstream> is included

Comment: Is there nothing else in your file? I would expect to see at least an include for the class you're implementing. Is the "myfile" error the first error? C++ errors usually come in avalanches so it's important to determine which one happened first (all yours depend on the first one).

Comment: @LewisCheng yes all the chars are replaced with wchar_ts in the first error.

Comment: Try place stdafx.h before anything else...

Comment: Because anything included before the precompiled header are thrown away by vc compiler...

Comment: But just the includes, any other macro, switch are still effective

Comment: @LewisCheng The first time I hear of a precompiled header

Comment: The precompiled header, as it implies, means the 'stdafx.h' is pre-compiled so that it does not need to be compiled again. This saves a lot of time to repeatedly compile the common standard headers like fstream, iostream...

Comment: @LewisCheng It also means that anything before `#include "stdafx.h"` is ignored.

Comment: @JamesKanze You are correct. to Matthias: That's not the recommended approach for modern c++ projects any more. It was introduced long long ago (from VC6?) since the computing resource at that time was very limited.

Comment: @LewisCheng I wouldn't go that far.  The way MS implemented pre-compiled headers is a bit strange, but on large projects (anything over a half a million LOC, say), they can still make a significant difference in build times.  But they shouldn't be the default, and you have to know how they are implemented, and how they work, before trying to use them.

Comment: @JamesKanze Yeah, MS implementation requires too much human effort to make use of stdafx.h correct. But other compiler toolsets (e.g., gcc) are more smart on header pre-compilation. In term of 'stdafx.h', the lgeacy from MFC should be thrown away indeed. It is hardly possible to include everything you need in a single stdafx.h especially your projects are extremely large.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The `stdafx.h` header must be the very first one to be included into
>   the .c/.cpp files. This is obligatory! Otherwise you are guaranteed to
>   get compilation errors.

Source: [StdAfx.h for Novices](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/2z86b7Xj/)

Therefore, the following includes

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include "stdafx.h"
```

should be reordered to

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
```

which ensures that `<iostream>` and `<fstream>` will now be included, and thus `std::basic_ofstream` will now be defined. This resolves the first error with regard to the local variable `myfile` and as a consequence resolves all the other errors related to this local variable `myfile` as well (as guessed/expected in an [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26868141/1731200)).

Answer (score 1):

Since the first error reports it couldn't figure out what `myfile` is, any subsequent code using `myfile` is almost sure to generate errors, even if it is correct.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: @msrd0: "can someone explain to me what I am doing wrong" was the question; I explained the source of the error in question, and (implicitly) which error should be focused on.